# post request to laravel route

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, post

I am trying to send this:

```
curl --insecure -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"UUID":"27486f-ea-11ee-bec0-fa163e4337e0","authtoken":"2748f6-e55a-11ee-b0-fa163e4337e0"}' https://<my server />/API/serveripupdate
```

With the route being

```
Route::any('/API/{method}/{jsondata}', 'API_c@apirequeststart');
```

The problem is that this does not seem to be recognised, returning my 'not found' html

```
<div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
    <div class="errorframe">
        <div class="code">
            404     </div>
        &nbsp;
        <div class="message">
            Not Found       </div>
        <div class="info">
                        <a href="https://asusrog.dev.liveinfo247.com/logout">Please Retry Login</a>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Route Testing**

When I use

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://<myserer />/API/serveripupdate/{"UUID":"27e7486f-e55a-11ee-bec0-fa163e4337e0","authtoken":"27e748f6-e55a-11ee-bec0-fa163e4337e0"}
```

This returns a response (and indeed stops at PHP breakpoint in PHPStorm where expected) however it shows that incomplete json would be processed as

```
$requestdata="UUID:27486f-ea-11ee-bec0-fa163e4337e0"
```

[image]

My question is what am I doing wrong in order to send JSON data via POST method on Ubuntu terminal, and ideally when working via crontab.
The aim is for the server to send its current IP address, however this is not part of the question, I need to get UUID and authtoken first from the JSON, obviously I would parse the IP from the request.

Comment: I maybe wrong but looking at the route, you are passing `jsondata` in path parameter, which you should not. Instead pass it as body since you are anyway using post method

Comment: gives a page expired error

Comment: Are you using wget? I would say stick with curl since you are attempting POST request

Comment: yes, I want to use curl, I showed wget above to demonstrate and check the route works from the same terminal session. I think a json request is best with curl. The route does not seem to recognise it

Answer (score 0):

Requires

\app\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php

to contain

```
 protected $except = [
  "/API/serveripupdate"
  ];
```

To access REST api use such as

wget --no-check-certificate https://myserver /API/serveripupdate/{"UUID":"27486ea-11ee-63e4337e0","authtoken":"2748f6-ea163e4337e0"}